# What is this bizarre in-growth in this red bell pepper?

Tags: genetics, food

I just chanced upon a rather strange red bell pepper (or capsicum?):

[image: bizarre bell pepper]

The green formation is bulbous to touch, just the like the outside of the bellpepper, and it has the same smell as one. I'm no biology expert, but I have a feeling that's a tiny ingrown bellpepper in there. My mom thinks it's a strange genetic experiment and wants me to throw it away!

What is that strange growth, and what might have caused it? Is this safe to consume?

Comment: These are "baby fruits" which are safe to eat. It's a quite common phenomenon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very likely to be [parthenocarpy](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/pepper/little-pepper-inside-pepper.htm), which is an “internal proliferation” and varies from an irregular fruit to an almost carbon copy of the larger pepper. What is known is that it shows up in seed lines through natural selection and is unaffected by weather, pests, or other external conditions. Please see page 27 of [this document](http://edepot.wur.nl/167546).